# Math.h function problem in c in code :: blocks

Tags: c

I wrote this code in C and it shows me this error.
I don't know what it is or how can I solve it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int z;
    scanf("%d", &z);
    double x1 , x2 , x3 , x4 , y1 , y2 , y3 , y4;
    for(int i = 0;i<=z;i++)
        {
    scanf("%lf %lf", &x1 , &y1);
    scanf("%lf %lf", &x2 , &y2);
    scanf("%lf %lf", &x3 , &y3);
    scanf("%lf %lf", &x4 , &y4);
    double tule_parekhat1 = sqrt(pow(y2-y1, 2) + (pow(x2-x1), 2));
    double tule_parekhat2 = sqrt(pow(y3-y2, 2) + (pow(x3-x2), 2));
    double tule_parekhat3 = sqrt(pow(y4-y1, 2) + (pow(x4-x1), 2));
    double tule_parekhat4 = sqrt(pow(y4-y3, 2) + (pow(x4-x3), 2));

    }

}
```

I get the error (line 15, error : too few arguments to function 'pow')

I don't know what it is.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the full error. We need to know the exact line and column. Better post the whole thing so you are sure you didn't miss anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains:

```
double tule_parekhat1 = sqrt(pow(y2-y1, 2) + (pow(x2-x1), 2));
```

with 2 call of `pow` function. In first call you correctly write `pow(y2-y1, 2)`, actually calling the function with 2 parameters. But in second one, you write:

```
(pow(x2-x1), 2)
```

Here you only call `pow` with the single `x2-x1` parameter and then use the comma (`,`) operator to discard that value and only retain the second one. This is incorrect and the compiler correctly raises an error.

You should write `pow(x2-x1, 2)` as you did for first call.

---

BTW, and IMHO you are abusing the `pow` function here. It is intended to be used for complex operation where both the operands are floating point values. Here the idiomatic way would be:

```
double tule_parekhat1 = sqrt((y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1) + (x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1));
...
```

using only addition and product operators.

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong usage of parentheses.

```
double tule_parekhat1 = sqrt(pow(y2-y1, 2) + (pow(x2-x1), 2));
```

in the `(pow(x2-x1), 2))` part, it should be

```
double tule_parekhat1 = sqrt(pow(y2-y1, 2) + pow(x2-x1, 2));
```

function `pow` sees only `x2-x1`